# Evaluating kinetic and potential energy of a single-body Hamiltonian in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, second-quantization

I am trying to derive the free Hamiltonian of a particle, specifically the kinetic and potential energy, which under second quantization, takes the form of

$$
\hat{T} = -\frac{\hbar^{2}}{2m}\int d\textbf{r} \left(\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\textbf{r}) \nabla^{2} \hat{\psi}(\textbf{r}) \right) \tag{1} \\
\hat{U} = \int d\textbf{r}\left(U(\textbf{r})\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\hat{\psi}(\textbf{r})\right)
$$

So I start with the fact that a generic one-body operator takes the form of

$$
\hat{O}=\sum_{\alpha,\alpha^{'}}\langle\alpha|o|\alpha^{'}\rangle a_{\alpha}^{\dagger}a_{\alpha^{'}} = \sum_{\alpha,\alpha^{'}}o_{\alpha,\alpha^{'}} a_{\alpha}^{\dagger}a_{\alpha^{'}} \tag{2}
$$
And I know that the transformation of basis ($\textbf{r}$ in this case) is given as

$$
a_{\textbf{r}}=\sum_{\alpha} \langle\textbf{r}|\alpha\rangle a_{\alpha} \\
\rightarrow \psi(\textbf{r})=\sum_{\alpha}\phi_{\alpha}(\textbf{r})a_{\alpha} \tag{3}
$$
where $\psi(\textbf{r})$ is now a field operator satisfying the commutation relation $[\psi(\textbf{r}),\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})]=\delta(r-r^{\prime})$. Using Eq. (2), the potential operator $\hat{U}$ is written as
$$
\hat{U}=\sum_{\alpha,\alpha^{'}}\langle\alpha|U(\textbf{r})|\alpha^{'}\rangle a_{\alpha}^{\dagger}a_{\alpha^{'}}\\
=\sum_{\alpha,\alpha^{'}}\int\int dr dr^{'}\langle\alpha|\textbf{r}\rangle\langle\textbf{r}|U(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\langle\textbf{r}^{'}|\alpha^{'}\rangle a_{\alpha}^{\dagger}a_{\alpha^{'}} \\
=\sum_{\alpha,\alpha^{'}}\int\int dr dr^{'}\phi_{\alpha}^{*}(\textbf{r})\langle\textbf{r}|U(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\phi_{\alpha^{'}}(\textbf{r}^{'}) a_{\alpha}^{\dagger}a_{\alpha^{'}} \\
=\int\int dr dr^{'}\langle\textbf{r}|U(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\psi(\textbf{r}^{'})
$$
where I have used (two) completeness relation $\int|\textbf{r}\rangle\langle\textbf{r}|d\textbf{r} = \mathbb{I}$ and $\int|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\langle\textbf{r}^{'}|d\textbf{r}^{'} = \mathbb{I}$

So at this step, I know that the delta function from the commutation relation of $\psi(\textbf{r})$ is used because I would need it to kill off one integral. But I don't see why legitimately I can factor out $U(\textbf{r})$ from $\langle\textbf{r}|U(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle$ so that
$$
\int\int dr dr^{'}\langle\textbf{r}|U(\textbf{r})|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\psi(\textbf{r}^{'}) \\
=\int\int dr dr^{'}U(\textbf{r})\langle\textbf{r}|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\psi(\textbf{r}^{'}) \\
=\int\int dr dr^{'}U(\textbf{r})\delta(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}^{'})\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\psi(\textbf{r}^{'})\\
=\int dr U(\textbf{r})\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\psi(\textbf{r})
$$
so that I get $\hat{U}$ from Eq.(1). Is the factoring out of $U(\textbf{r})$ permitted here? How should I evaluate it in the case of kinetic energy where I have to evaluate $\langle\textbf{r}|\nabla^{2}|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle$?

Thanks

Comment: What about to change coordinate representation to momentum, $|r\rangle\rightarrow|p\rangle$, i.e. perfrom Fourier transform of $\psi$-operators, which means that $\nabla\rightarrow\pm ip$ (choose you own sign)?

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov thanks for your response. However, I'm trying to understand this in the position basis

Comment: For your first question the operator $U(\hat{\mathbf{r}})$ is a function of the position operator so, by definition it has the same eigenstates as the position operator and its eigenvalues are given by $U(\mathbf{r})$ (note the lack of a hat on the $\mathbf{r}$). Your second question is addressed [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/380091/how-to-interpret-langle-x-hat-qx-rangle-for-a-quantum-mechanical-operator)

Comment: @Symmetry Thank you for your response. Your explanation of $U(\textbf{r})$ makes sense to me. I have been reading on the link that you gave about the second part. I don't quite follow on applying what you wrote to what I have here. My issue is that the Laplacian is sandwiched in between $\psi^{\dagger}$ and $\psi$, post evaluation and I don't see how to get there

Comment: @Symmetry In the context of my problem. Can you elaborate on how I can proceed from evaluating $\int\int d\textbf{r}d\textbf{r}^{'}\langle\textbf{r}|\nabla^{2}|\textbf{r}^{'}\rangle\psi^{\dagger}(\textbf{r})\psi(\textbf{r}^{'})$ ?